# Statistical significance of a classifier's precision

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Suppose I have a sample of $n$ data points (examples) that have to be classified into one of two classes (positive and negative). Let's say I have a method to generate a score for each example. The higher the score, the higher the probability that it's of the positive class.

I have the true labels for a subset containing $m$ of those data points. To be concrete, say there are total 1500 examples and I have true labels for 250 of them. Now I want to set a scoring threshold based on these 250 examples. The idea is:

- Set a threshold $T$. Assume $r$ out of the $m$ labeled examples have scores $>=T$
- Find the precision of the positive class among these remaining $r$ examples. I can then select a threshold value if I get a high enough precision

Continuing with the numbers I gave above, suppose 75 out of 250 examples have a score of more than or equal to 80. Out of those 75, 72 turn out to be true positives. So for the threshold value of 80, I get a precision value of 96%.

Naturally I cannot set arbitrarily high thresholds since the sample size will decrease and my confidence in the efficacy of the threshold value will go down. My question is: **how do I find the statistical significance / confidence level of the sample precision representing the true precision?**

(By "sample precision" I mean the one calculated as described in the question. By "true precision" I mean the precision I'd get if I ran the classification method - **with the threshold I selected via the method above** - on the rest of the examples. i.e. calculate score for all examples and classify ones with threshold >= 80 as positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your test classifications are [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables), (i.e., each case is IID and you are not using K-fold cross-validation or some other method that induces dependencies between different outcomes), you can consider your precision measure as a binomial random variable. A [binomial confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) would give you a range that contains the 'real' precision of your classification rule with high (e.g. 0.95) probability.

In Python, you can that with *statsmodels*:

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint 
proportion_confint(72,75,method='beta')   

(0.8875231782399902, 0.9916738343339206)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But I thought calculation of confidence interval would take into account the size of the sample relative to the population? Does that factor in or is the absolute size of the same sufficient, regardless of population?

Comment: The population is by definition infinite. For larger samples, the confidence interval will be smaller. For example, if you had 720 successes out of 750 tries, the same confidence interval would shrink to 94.3%-97.2%.

Comment: Perfectly clear. Thanks so much! Would you mind answering a very quick follow-up question? Should I ask in the comments or post it as a separate question?