# Statistical Significance of precision WITHOUT negative labels

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, conditional-probability

This is a follow-up to my earlier question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466136/statistical-significance-of-a-classifiers-precision/466142). Let there be $n$ data points (examples) to be classified into 2 classes - either positive or negative. Let's say we have a model that outputs the probability of an example being of the positive class. I want to decide on an appropriate threshold for the probability - an example will be predicted as positive if the corresponding probability is more than the threshold.

The constraint is that I only know that $k$ of those examples are positives. I have **no information** on any true negatives. So for example if there are total 1500 examples, I might only know that 50 of them are positive class, and that's it.

If I set a threshold $T$, then I can count the no. of true positive examples whose probability score exceeds $T$. This gives me probability on the sample $P(>T\ |\ pos)$ where "$>T$" is the event of an example's probabilty score exceeding $T$. Then

$$P(pos\ |\ >T)=\frac{P(>T\ |\ pos)P(pos)}{P(>T)}$$

Now I know $P(>T)$ - I can just count the no. of examples exceeding the threshold. Assuming I have an estimate for $P(pos)$ as well, there's still the problem that $P(>T\ |\ pos)$ has been estimated on the sample and I don't know how it affects the final estimate of $P(pos\ |\ >T)$.

**Doubt: Is there a way to calculate some measure of confidence for the final probability estimate that I calculate?**

Comment: 1. The probability you are interested in is the positive predictive value (PPV). Have a look at Steinberg, D. M., Fine, J., & Chappell, R. (2009). Sample size for positive and negative predictive value in diagnostic research using case–control designs. Biostatistics, 10(1), 94-105.

Comment: 2. Usually, one needs a specificity estimate for estimating the PPV. You circumvent that in how you estimate the denominator, but this 'trick' implies making strong assumptions about your 1500 samples. Namely, you assume that they are representative of the general population in terms of prevalence - P(POS). Also, you implicitly assume that your labeled positive sample is representative of the positive population. These assumptions might be warranted or not, depending on how the data was collected and the reason for the masking of the labels of most of your samples.